# “Cannot read property 'props' of undefined” in the catch error function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the `fetch()` call below, when the URL is successfully fetched, `setAudio()` is successfully called but when an error is caught while fetching, I get:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSearch' of undefined

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  if (isNaN(audio.duration)) {
    if (this.props.keywords.length != 0) {
      if (audio.getAttribute("src") == "") {
        // Call to handleSearch() here is working fine.
        this.handleSearch(this.props.keywords[this.props.currentKey]);
      }
    }
  }
}

handleSearch = value => {
  fetch("URL" + value).then(res => res.json()).then(result => {
    // Some code
    this.props.setAudio({currentSourceId});
  }).catch(error => {
    // Some code
    this.handleSearch(this.props.keywords[this.props.currentKey]);
  });
}
```

In the bundled `JS` file, I found:

```
n.handleSearch = function(e) {
  fetch("URL" + e).then(function(e) {
    return e.json()
  }).then(function(i) {
    // Some Code
    n.props.setAudio({currentSourceId: a})
  }).catch(function(e) {
    // Some Code
    this.handleSearch(this.props.keywords[this.props.currentKey])
  })
}
```

`n` is used to refer to `this` here, but inside catch, `this` it is still `this`. This is why I'm getting this error. Why is it still `this`?

Comment: there's not enough here. can you provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your query needs the component code to be shared for us to help you with the fix

Comment: it loks like `handleSearch` is in a `static` scope.

Comment: @DanielA.White I have updated my question.

Comment: @Think-Twice I have added some more code to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just deployed my app again and now it's fixed. Now, in my bundled `JS`, I have:

```
n.handleSearch = function(e) {
  fetch("URL" + e).then(function(e) {
    return e.json()
  }).then(function(i) {
    // Some Code
    n.props.setAudio({currentSourceId: a})
  }).catch(function(e) {
    // Some Code
    n.handleSearch(n.props.keywords[n.props.currentKey])
  })
}
```